# How prove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_{1}}+\frac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}}}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Assume that a positive term series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges,
show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}}=0.$$

My try: since $a_{n}>0$. so
$$\dfrac{n^2}{\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}}>0.$$

But I can't find this right limit is zero!.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let  $\varepsilon >0$.
There is an index $r$ such that $\sum_{k=r}^{\infty}a_k \leq \frac{4}{9}\varepsilon$.

Let $n\geq r$. Consider the $n-r+1$ numbers $a_r,a_{r+1}, \ldots,a_n$. The
[generalized means inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) 
implies that

$$
M_{-1}(a_r,a_{r+1}, \ldots,a_n) \leq M_{0}(a_r,a_{r+1}, \ldots,a_n) \tag{1}
$$

i.e.

$$
\frac{n-r+1}{\sum_{k=r}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k}} \leq \frac{\sum_{k=r}^n a_k}{n-r+1} \tag{2}
$$

This implies that

$$
\frac{n^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k}} \leq \frac{n^2}{\sum_{k=r}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k}} \leq
\big(\frac{n}{n-r+1}\big)^2 \big(\sum_{k=r}^n a_k \big) \leq
\big(\frac{n}{n-r+1}\big)^2 \frac{4}{9}\varepsilon
$$

Now, if we take $n\geq 3(r-1)$ we will have $\frac{n}{n-r+1} \leq \frac{3}{2}$
so $\big(\frac{n}{n-r+1}\big)^2 \leq \frac{9}{4}$ and hence

$$
\frac{n^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k}} \leq \varepsilon
$$

which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a far from rigorous argument.  Because

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$$

this implies that $a_n < (1/C) n^{-1-\epsilon}$ $\forall \, \epsilon > 0$ and some $C>0$.  Therefore $1/a_n >C  n^{1+\epsilon}$.  By the integral test,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n} \gt C' n^{2+\epsilon}$$

for $C' >0$.  Therefore, the expression in the limit behaves as $(1/C') n^{-\epsilon}$ as $n \to \infty$, and the limit is zero.

Comment: Thank,why implies that $a_{n}<(1/C)n^{-1-\xi},\forall \xi>0$?

Comment: @chinamath: because, e.g., the integral test.  It is known that a harmonic series diverges, but anything in a positive series that falls off faster than $1/n$ converges.

Comment: why $\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}>Cn^{1+\xi}\Longrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}>C'n^{2+\xi}$?

Comment: Again, integral test.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to find some bounds $C(n, \{a_k\}_{k=1}^n)$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} C(n, \{a_k\}_{k=1}^n) = 0$ such that 
$$\frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}}
\le C(n, \{a_k\}_{k=1}^n).$$

I knew two bounds as follows. The proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty} C(n, \{a_k\}_{k=1}^n) = 0$ is easy and thus omitted.

1) We have
$$\frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}}
\le 4\sum_{k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}^n a_k.$$
Remark: This solution is the same as @Ewan Delanoy's one.

2) We have
$$\frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}}
\le \frac{\mathrm{e}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k.
$$

$\phantom{2}$

Some proofs:

For the first bound: By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}}
&\le \frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}} + \frac{1}{a_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor+1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}}\\
&\le \frac{n^2}{(n - \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1)^2}
(a_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} + a_{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1} + \cdots + a_n)\\
&\le 4\sum_{k = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}^n a_k.
\end{align}

For the second bound: By using GM-HM and AM-GM, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{n^2}{\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}}
&\le n(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{1/n}\\
&= \frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}} (a_1\cdot 2a_2 \cdot 3a_3 \cdots na_n)^{1/n}\\
&\le \frac{1}{(n!)^{1/n}} \sum_{k=1}^n ka_k\\
&\le \frac{\mathrm{e}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k
\end{align}
where we have used the Stirling approximation to get $(n!)^{1/n} \ge \frac{n+1}{\mathrm{e}}$.